# Serviços do WIndows 10

Tags: mysql, windows-10

Boa tarde pessoal, estou com um problema no SERVIÇO do Windows 10.
Instalei o MySQL Server e WorkBench para trabalhar com BD e Modelagem porem o MySQL Server que baixei não esta compatível com o que estou usando na Faculdade, lá usamos o 5.7 na faculdade e o qual baixei foi o 8.0, com isso, precisei desinstalar todo o programa pra baixar o que queria(5.7) mas no Serviço do Windows ele continua com a seguinte informação:

> MySql80: falha ao ler descrição. Código de erro:2

Como faço para tirar o server completamente da minha maquina, já apaguei do Editor de Registro mas agora ele da essa informação a cima e continua no Serviço.

Comment: vc já tentou remover o serviço? E outra, da pra instalar mais de uma instância do mysql

Comment: Já tentei sim e não consegui, aparentemente não esta se ativando em segundo plano. Sei sim mas quando tentei baixar o 5.7 deu erro no processo.

Comment: Tentou isso 'sc delete service_name'? Lembrando, num prompt aberto como adm

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>sc delete service_MySQL80
[SC] OpenService FALHA 1060:

O serviço especificado não existe como serviço instalado.


C:\Windows\system32>

Deu essa informação, quer dizer que ele não esta instalado então??

Comment: Abre o services e confere o nome dele. se vc não encontrar então é pq ele foi excluido, caso encontre, de um botão direito e copie o campo nome do serviço. (cara, apaga o 'service_' deixe somente o nome do serviço )

Comment: Isso deve ajudar: http://www.dicasparacomputador.com/como-remover-servicos-windows

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remova o serviço do windows. Par isso, abra um prompt como administrador e execute o comando:

```
sc delete 'service_name'
```

substituindo *'service_name'* pelo nome exato do serviço que você quer remover, no seu caso, *'MySQL80'*.

Depois disso, instale o mySql na versão correta.